# Creating Stake Account using CLI

Tags: account, cli, stake

I am using the following command using the reference link as https://docs.solana.com/cli/delegate-stake. However, I am getting an error - "Error: Dynamic program error: missing signature for supplied pubkey: Dt5PcGz....."

```
solana create-stake-account --from <Pubkey of stake account address> stake-account.json 0.1 --stake-authority <Pubkey of stake account address> --withdraw-authority <Pubkey of stake account address> --fee-payer <Pubkey of stake account address>
```

Please note the  is generated by the following command and corresponding output

```
solana-keygen new --no-passphrase -o stake-account.json
Generating a new keypair
Wrote new keypair to stake-account.json
==========================================================================
pubkey: Dt5PcGz.........................
==========================================================================
Save this seed phrase to recover your new keypair:
lion .... .... 
==========================================================================
```

Answer (score 1):

The `--from` parameter in `create-stake-account` will transfer funds from that account, and the `--fee-payer` will pay for it, so there's two problems.

By providing just a pubkey to `from` and `fee-payer`, the CLI can't get signatures, causing an immediate failure. You can fix this by passing `stake-account.json` to both of those.

Next, if the stake account has no SOL in it, it cannot be the fee payer or the "from" address, so make sure that it has funds in it.